# Boost.Graph with Bellman-Ford: Invalid read

Tags: c++, memory, boost, segmentation-fault, boost-graph

I am using the Boost.Graph library to find the shortest path in a graph with the Bellman-Ford algorithm. However, my program gets killed in execution.

I have prepared a snippet of my code:

```
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double > Weight;
typedef boost::adjacency_list < boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, Weight > DirectedGraph;

DirectedGraph g;


std::vector<Node> list;

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    list.push_back(Node(rand() % 100)); // getValue() will return this value
}


std::vector<std::pair<Order, DirectedGraph::vertex_descriptor>> values;

for(auto v : list)
{
    values.push_back(std::pair<Node, DirectedGraph::vertex_descriptor>(v, boost::add_vertex(g)));
}

for(auto v : values)
    {
        for(auto u : values)
        {
        if(v == u)
            continue;
        else if(/* some conditions are met*/)
            boost::add_edge(v.second, u.second, -std::log(u.first.getValue()), g);
    }
}

boost::property_map<DirectedGraph, boost::edge_weight_t>::type weight_pmap = get(boost::edge_weight_t(), g);
unsigned int nb_vertices = boost::num_vertices(g);

for(auto v : values)
{

        if(/* v meets conditions to be a source vertex*/)
        {
        int entry_point = v.second;
        std::vector<double> distance(nb_vertices, (std::numeric_limits < double >::max)());
                distance[entry_point] = 0;

        std::vector<std::size_t> parent(nb_vertices);
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nb_vertices; i++)
                    parent[i] = i;

        bool r = boost::bellman_ford_shortest_paths(
                    g,
                     nb_vertices,
                      weight_map(weight_pmap).
                       distance_map(&distance[entry_point]).
                        predecessor_map(&parent[entry_point])
              );
    }
}
```

I programmed it with slight changes to the [official example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/example/bellman-example.cpp).

As I said already the program gets killed mid-execution. I used *gdb* and *valgrind* to get some more detailed error messages:

**gdb**:

```
 Error in ...: double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000000cdadb0 

    Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
    0x00007ffff5abdcc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
    56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: File or Directory not found
    (gdb) where
    #0  0x00007ffff5abdcc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
    #1  0x00007ffff5ac10d8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
    #2  0x00007ffff5afa394 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff5c08b28 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
    #3  0x00007ffff5b0666e in malloc_printerr (ptr=<optimized out>, str=0x7ffff5c08c58 "double free or corruption (out)", action=1) at malloc.c:4996
    #4  _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3840
    #5  0x000000000055297e in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<unsigned long>::deallocate (this=0x7fffffffd010, __p=0xcdadb0) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:110
    #6  0x0000000000550d5c in std::_Vector_base<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >::_M_deallocate (this=0x7fffffffd010, __p=0xcdadb0, __n=14) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:174
    #7  0x000000000054eea1 in std::_Vector_base<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >::~_Vector_base (this=0x7fffffffd010, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:160
    #8  0x000000000054db67 in std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >::~vector (this=0x7fffffffd010, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:416
    #9  0x000000000054a32e in OrderList::makePaths () at ../BetherV2/Global/OrderList/orderlist.cpp:343
    #10 0x00000000004b1e16 in main () at ../BetherV2/main.cpp:33
```

**Valgrind**:

```
==5476== Invalid read of size 8
==5476==    at 0x55452E: bool boost::relax<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property>, boost::n$
==5476==    by 0x552CE3: bool boost::bellman_ford_shortest_paths<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::$
==5476==    by 0x550F4F: bool boost::detail::bellman_dispatch2<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no$
==5476==    by 0x54F0D0: bool boost::detail::bellman_dispatch<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_$
==5476==    by 0x54DC91: bool boost::bellman_ford_shortest_paths<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::$
==5476==    by 0x54A318: OrderList::makePaths() (orderlist.cpp:354)
==5476==    by 0x4B1E15: main (main.cpp:33)
==5476==  Address 0x1e313340 is 0 bytes after a block of size 112 alloc'd
==5476==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5476==    by 0x553C9D: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<double>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
==5476==    by 0x552898: std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /home/alex/C++/build-BetherV2-Desktop-Debug/BetherV2)
==5476==    by 0x550BCE: std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_create_storage(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:181)
==5476==    by 0x54ECDC: std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_Vector_base(unsigned long, std::allocator<double> const&) (stl_vector.h:136)
==5476==    by 0x54D9F1: std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::vector(unsigned long, double const&, std::allocator<double> const&) (stl_vector.h:283)
==5476==    by 0x54A1A5: OrderList::makePaths() (orderlist.cpp:340)
==5476==    by 0x4B1E15: main (main.cpp:33)

--5476-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--5476-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x9;  sp: 0x802f9ddd0

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal
```

In the *gdb* errors, "orderlist.cpp:343" reffers to `std::vector<std::size_t> parent(nb_vertices);`

In the *valgrind* errors, "orderlist.cpp:340" reffers to `std::vector<double> distance(nb_vertices, (std::numeric_limits < double >::max)());`

I am trying to fix this since yesterday but I cannot find the source of the problem. It seems like the Bellman-Ford algorithm tries to access the distance/parent maps outside their bounds. But why should that happen?

Comment: Can you post a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: [I got my hopes up](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/858faca9f375867a). Your move

Comment: I ran the boost sample program, but when I try to use your code, I have undefined classes Node and Order. Also, there are two if(/*comment/*)

Comment: Can you try `[...].distance_map(&distance[0]).            predecessor_map(&parent[0]))`?

Comment: @jv_ Ohh I see it works now. I though I had to put in the index of the source node.